# Calling and linking a child and parent class together in Java

Tags: java

Okay i know the title sounds like a duplicate, but i assure you i've tried to find similar questions but none quite seem to fit. If you can find it, downvote this and link it, i'll be happy to remove.

The aim is a simple one: I want to create a 'Bank Account' Program that takes in the input of the user, such as the Bank A/C number, balance and type, identifies the type of account based on that and outputs it for the user to see.

I have created three classes as shown below(only three for the sake of simplicity)

1) The Parent Class 'An arbitrary account of no type'

```
public class ParentAccount {
    private String acctNumber;
    private double balance;

    public ParentAccount(String acctNumber, double balance){
        this.acctNumber = acctNumber;
        this.balance = balance;

    }

    public ParentAccount(){
        this.acctNumber = "0";
        this.balance = 0;

    }


    public String toString(){
        return String.format("A/C no:%s, Balance=%.2f", acctNumber, balance);
    }
}
```

2) The Child Class 'The account of a Checking type'

```
    public class CheckingAccount extends ParentAccount {
    private int limit = 10000;
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Bank [" + super.toString() + ",limit=" + limit + "]";

    }
}
```

3) The main executing class

```
    import java.util.Scanner;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String BankAC;
        Double BankBalance;
        String type;


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Bank Account Number:  ");
        BankAC = scan.next();
        System.out.printf("Now Enter the balance:   ");
        BankBalance = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Now enter the type of bank account:  ");
        type = scan.next();


        ParentAccount P1 = new ParentAccount(BankAC, BankBalance);

            if("Checking".equals(type)){


                ParentAccount P1 = new CheckingAccount();

                System.out.println(P1);

            }

    }
}
```

For example:

I input bank A/c as 11234, balance as 100, type as Checking

Output: Bank A/c:0 Balance: 0 limit = 10000

From what i can tell, the code seems to take the DEFAULT constructor in my parent class instead of the user constructor, which i can understand why.

What i cant get is how to get around this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You create a `ParentAccount` with the variables given by the user, then if it's a checking account you throw it away (well, you ignore it) and create a new blank `CheckingAccount` which you then display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost tempted to call this a typo, but your code is doing *exactly* what you told it to do.

Recall that your `ParentAccount` constructor is overloaded.  It either does or doesn't accept parameters.  If it does have parameters, it'll put the value in as necessary; if it doesn't, it won't bother.

This is true for your child class as well; it is *implicitly* calling `super()` when it's being instantiated, so you'll get `ParentAccount`'s no-arg constructor invoked instead.

A few things you'd need to do to make this work:

- Add a constructor to `CheckingAccount` which simply calls the parent constructor.

  ```
  public CheckingAccount(String acctNumber, double balance) {
      super(acctNumber, balance);
  }
  ```
- *Properly* instantiate an instance of `CheckingAccount` depending on type.

  ```
  ParentAccount account;
  if("Checking".equals(type)) {
      account = new CheckingAccount(BankAC, BankBalance);
  } else {
      account = new ParentAccount(BankAC, BankBalance);
  }

  System.out.println(account);
  ```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You only have a constructor for the parent class, if you want to have the information stored again when you create P1 as a new checkingAccount object, you need to create a constructor for checkingAccount as well.

You are creating a new instance for P1 with no values passed, so the old values are lost.

I recommend something like this

```
public CheckingAccount(String acctnumber, double balance){
    super(acctnumber, balance);
}
```

and creating P1 like

```
ParentAccount P1 = new CheckingAccount(BancAC, BankBalance);
```

Answer (score 0):

The child class CheckingAccount only have: "default constructor"

And the code:

```
ParentAccount P1 = new CheckingAccount();
System.out.println(P1);
```

No contain any data.